# VBA: Error message code still being executed despite Exit Sub command beforehand

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, messagebox

I have some code creating a worksheet which is deleted if a worksheet with the same name is already present in the workbook. If a duplicate is present, the code should jump to the `Errmsg` to create an alert and does. However, when the worksheet isn't a duplicate it still runs through the rest of the code and the error message at the end despite an Exit Sub command before it, therefore deleting the sheet that was just created.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
On Error GoTo Errmsg

'Some code

Exit Sub

Errmsg:
    MsgBox "Worksheet with that name already exists, please edit the test iteration"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Delete
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This could be a problem with your other code.  Could you include it for completeness please?

Comment: Your code is likely just breaking somewhere else. Comment out the `On Error GoTo Errmsg` line and see where it breaks exactly

Comment: Alternatively you could add properties of the `Err` object to the msgbox's contents, such as `Err.Description`. This should give you an idea of the type of error. Right now, a message for one type of error will be shown for all possible error types your code could run into.

Comment: Use the `On Error Goto Errmsg` _only_ around the statement for which you want to catch the error, and reset it after the statement with `On Error Goto 0`

Comment: @TimStack Thanks, I'm an idiot! It was a small error in the code right before the Exit Sub and error message which is why I thought it might be running through the code fine.